# Run function after response has been returned

Tags: python, flask, callback

In Flask, how could I run a function after returning a response for a particular route? For example:

```
# This function takes a long time to run
def long_func():
    ...


 @app.route('/')
 def index():
    ...
    return response
```

If I wanted to run long_func after returning the response for only the index route, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to redirect to a route calling the long function after calling your index :

you can do something like this :

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    ...
    return redirect(url_for('run_long_function'))
@app.route('/runLongFunc')
def run_long_function():
    long_func()
    return 'done'
```